# Loading image in ListView from Array ID Android

Tags: android, mysql, json, listadapter

I currently have a ListAdapter set up that is passed information pulled from a MYSQL database via JSON. I'm trying to display an image I have stored in the drawable folder based on the ID of the product. e.g For Product 1 R.drawable.img1 is shown in and so on..

```
public class GetProducts extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSON jParser = new JSON();
Functions uf = new Functions();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://jumpto.be/api/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_IMGURL = "image";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    new GetProductsFromDB().execute();
    // Loading products in Background Thread


    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    /*lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    OrderBuild.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });*/

}



class GetProductsFromDB extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetProducts.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_all_products, params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String ImgUrl = c.getString(TAG_PID);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    String imageLink = "R.drawable.img"+id;
                    map.put(TAG_IMGURL, imageLink);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map); 
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {



                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        GetProducts.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_IMGURL},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.img });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

The current code I have just tells me it cannot find the directory. I have looked at URI but I can't figure out how I run them in the array / for loop.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`R.drawable.img1` is actually just an int value defined in your automatically generated `R.java` file, so you cannot use it directly.

However, you can retrieve your drawable using the following:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
int resId = resources.getIdentifier("img" + id, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable myDrawable = resources.getDrawable(resId);
```

Alternatively, you can place your image files in your `assets` directory and load them from there using the filename.

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("img" + id + ".jpg");
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would I assign that to the ListAdapter? Is it through 
    Map.put

Answer (score 0):

You can set int value for drawable in hashmap. It is easy to bind in list adapter.

int imageLink = R.drawable.img1;
map.put(TAG_IMGURL, imageLink);